# Libgdx Box2D Velocity is just not fast enough

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have a rectangle that I would like to move fast but for what ever reason the faster velocity I use still seems slow. What am I doing wrong? I have also dropped a circle from above onto a surface and even tough I play with gravity it comes down like a ballon...

Some declarations

```
float velocity = 10000000f;
static final float BOX_STEP=1/60f;  
static final int BOX_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS=6;  
static final int BOX_POSITION_ITERATIONS=2;
```

Gravity, tried everything and they all seem to suck

world = new World(new Vector2(0, -50), true);

The ground my object is moving onto

```
    //ground
    BodyDef groundBodyDef =new BodyDef();  
    groundBodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(0, camera.viewportHeight * .08f));  
    Body groundBody = world.createBody(groundBodyDef);  
    PolygonShape groundBox = new PolygonShape();  
    groundBox.setAsBox((camera.viewportWidth) * 2, camera.viewportHeight * .08f);  
    groundBody.createFixture(groundBox, 0.0f);
```

And then here are my objects:

```
    //ball
    bodyDef = new BodyDef();  
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;  
    bodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(camera.viewportWidth * .2f, camera.viewportHeight * .75f));  
    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);  
    CircleShape dynamicCircle = new CircleShape();  
    dynamicCircle.setRadius(camera.viewportWidth * .035f);  
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();  
    fixtureDef.shape = dynamicCircle;  
    fixtureDef.density = 0.5f;  
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.5f;  
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.8f;  
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef); 
    body.setLinearVelocity(0,-100);

    //slime boy
    BodyDef bodyBoxDef = new BodyDef();  
    bodyBoxDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;  
    bodyBoxDef.position.set(new Vector2(camera.viewportWidth * .08f,camera.viewportHeight * .191f));  
    bodyBox = world.createBody(bodyBoxDef);  
    PolygonShape slimeBox = new PolygonShape();  
    slimeBox.setAsBox(camera.viewportWidth * .04f, camera.viewportHeight * .03f);
    FixtureDef fixtureSlimeDef = new FixtureDef();  
    fixtureSlimeDef.shape = slimeBox;  
    fixtureSlimeDef.density = 1.0f;  
    fixtureSlimeDef.friction = 0.0f;  
    fixtureSlimeDef.restitution = 0.0f;  
    bodyBox.createFixture(fixtureSlimeDef);  

    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer(); 

    body.applyTorque(1000000000);
    bodyBox.setFixedRotation(true);
    bodyBox.setBullet(true);
```

Any one have suggestions to speed up all movement in this?

I have been using a screen 1280 by 720 but I saw from other sources smaller is better so I scaled down to 640 by 260 but still not the preformance I want. How small should I really go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Box2d Manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html) (Section 2.2):

> Box2D is tuned for meters, kilograms, and seconds. So you can consider
>   the extents to be in meters. Box2D generally works best when objects
>   are the size of typical real world objects. For example, a barrel is
>   about 1 meter tall. Due to the limitations of floating point
>   arithmetic, using Box2D to model the movement of glaciers or dust
>   particles is not a good idea.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4556714/960524

Comment: Yes I just realized this and I have made world to meter conversions. The only thing now, my velocity moves fast but so fast it skips over a bunch of values but I will learn to resolve this. Thank you!