# libGDX - My Box2D Body doesnt jump

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

I'm trying to make a little game with the java game engine called libGDX. I already got the player but he can't jump and I dont know why.

This is my GameScreen class:

```
public class GameScreen extends ScreenManager{
    //For the view of the game and the rendering
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;

    //DEBUG
    private Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;

    //World, Player and so on
    private GameWorld world;
    private Player player;
    private Ground ground;


    public static float w, h;

    public GameScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);
        //vars
        w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        //view and rendering
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, w/2, h/2);

        //debug
        b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        //world, bodies ...
        player = new Player(world);
        ground = new Ground(world);

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {


    }

    @Override
    public void show() {


    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        //clearing the screen
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //updating
        update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        //render
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        //debug
        b2dr.render(world.getWorld(), cam.combined);    


    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {


    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {


    }


    @Override
    public void dispose() {


    }

    @Override
    public void onKlick(float delta) {


    }

    public void update(float delta){
        world.update(delta);
        player.keyInput();
        System.out.println(player.getBody().getPosition().x);
        System.out.println(player.getBody().getPosition().y);
    }



}
```

and this is my Player class:

```
public class Player {
    public static Body body;
    public static BodyDef def;
    private FixtureDef fd;

    //set form
    private PolygonShape shape;

    private GameScreen gs;

    public Player(GameWorld world){
        def = new BodyDef();
        def.fixedRotation = true;
        def.position.set(gs.w / 4, gs.h / 4);
        def.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;

        body = world.getWorld().createBody(def);

        shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(32 / 2, 32 / 2);

        fd = new FixtureDef();
        fd.shape = shape;
        fd.density = 30;

        body.createFixture(fd);
        shape.dispose();
    }

    public static Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public static BodyDef getDef() {
        return def;
    }

    public static void keyInput(){
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)){
            body.applyForceToCenter(0, 900, false);
            System.out.println("PRESSED");
        }
    }



}
```

this finally is my GameWorld class:

```
public class GameWorld {
    public static World world;

    public GameWorld(){
        world = new World(new Vector2(0f, -10f), false);

    }

    public void update(float delta){
        world.step(1 / 60f, 5, 2);
        System.out.println("WorldUPDATE");
    }

    public static World getWorld() {
        return world;
    }



}
```

I don't know why the body can't jump please help me if you can (: Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Force pushes the body each timestep, while gravity pushes it back down again. There is a function [applyLinearImpulse()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body.html#applyLinearImpulse-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2-boolean-) which pushes it like once with all its "force" before gravity interferention.

When you are using [applyForceToCenter()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body.html#applyForceToCenter-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2-boolean-) body should be pushed up, but its very slow process compared to impulse.

Comment: ok thank you so much for your answer. Can you give me a example please?

Comment: yeaa it worked! Thank you so much but now everything looks very very slow. Do you know how to fix that too?

Comment: Its because you don't scale your player size, so Box2d considers it being much bigger than u see (meters instead of pixels).
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701142/libgdx-box2d-velocity-is-just-not-fast-enough

Comment: Ouuuh :D Thank you so much for helping me out :D